# Center object in view opengl

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I have a 3d object which I want to keep in the center of my view. If I were to translate the object I want the camera to move with it and keep the object in the center of the screen. How would I do this with opengl and libgdx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gluLookAt`](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/GLU.html#gluLookAt%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) will do what you want.

pseudocode:

```
float objPos[3];
float camPos[3] = objPos - float[3]{0, 0, 3} //camera 3 units behind object on Z axis
float upVec[3] = { 0, 1, 0}

onDraw {
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(camPos[0], camPos[1], camPos[2], objPos[0], objPos[1], objPos[2], upVec[0], upVec[1], upVec[2]);

    ...draw...
}
```